# SwiftUI: How to clip just the bottom of an image

Tags: image, swiftui

I have an image which I wish to pin to the top of the view with a height of 200. I started with the following:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image("frog")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .frame(height:200)

            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

which gives me:

[image]

You can see the frame (with height 200) outlined in blue. Now, I want the image to continue to spill out of the safe zone to fill the top of the view, as it is doing. But I want clip the image at its bottom frame, so I get something like this:

[image]

I'd also be fine with something like this, where the whole image is shifted upwards to where the natural bottom of the image is at the bottom of the frame:

[image]

I've tried a wide array of modifiers, as well as using `GeometryReader` but have not been able to achieve either result. **I need this to work for images of arbitrary dimensions.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is alternate that gives you effect of your 2nd screenshot:

```swift
Image("frog")
    .resizable()
    .scaledToFill()
    .frame(height:200)
    .mask(Rectangle().edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)) // << here !!
```

Answer (score 10):

To shift the image upwards you can do the following:

```
.frame(height:200, alignment: .bottom)
```